# How to translate a complex nested JSON structure into multiple columns in a Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am learning Scala, and am trying to filter a select few columns from a large nested json file to make into a DataFrame. This is the gist of the json:

```
{
  “meta”: 
    {“a”: 1, b: 2”}    // I want to ignore meta
  “objects”:
  [
    {
         “caucus”: “Progressive”,
     “person” : 
         {
          “name”: “Mary”,
          “party”: “Green Party”,
          “age”: 50,
          “gender”: “female” // etc..
         }
    }, // etc.
   ] 
}
```

Hence the data looks like this as is, read in with spark.

```
    val df = spark.read.json("file")
    df.show()
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                meta|             objects|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[limit -> 100.0, ...|[[, [116.0, 117.0...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Instead of this, I want a DataFrame with the columns: Name | Party | Caucus.

I've messed around with explode() and have reproduced the schema as a StructType(), but am not sure how to deal with a nested structure like this in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ".*" on a column of type struct to tranform it it into multiple fields columns:

```
val df = spark.read.json("file.json")
df.select(col("meta"), explode(col("objects")).as("objects"))
  .select("meta.*", "objects.*")
  .select("a", "b", "caucus", "person.*")
  .show(false)


+---+---+-----------+---+------+----+-----------+
|a  |b  |caucus     |age|gender|name|party      |
+---+---+-----------+---+------+----+-----------+
|1  |2  |Progressive|50 |female|Mary|Green Party|
+---+---+-----------+---+------+----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no generic way to handle it because of course it depends on the shape of your data. In your case, you want to explode an array, which will create a column called `col`, that will contain structs.
You can then access the fields within the struct using the dot notation, so to extract the fields you asked for you can do this:

```
df.select(explode_outer($"objects")).
  select(
     $"col.caucus", 
     $"col.person.name",
     $"col.person.party").show

+-----------+----+-----------+
|     caucus|name|      party|
+-----------+----+-----------+
|Progressive|Mary|Green Party|
+-----------+----+-----------+
```